# Horizontal listView with 1 item visible at a time

Tags: android, android-listview

I want to implement `Horizontal listView` with only 1 item visible at a time. I have implemented [this project](http://www.dev-smart.com/archives/34) but the items appear next to each other.

I want the only 1 item in screen at a time the next item should come in when scrolled

Comment: Inside getView() method try to set the width of the view to screen size and lets see how is is coming, hope this will solve your issue.

Comment: I tried that it is not working

Comment: create a linear layout and inside that create a simple view, and use that as the item for your Listview and once getView is called try to set the width for the view insdie the linear layout.